# Get the address of a function generated via macro

Tags: c++, macros, function-pointers

I try to use code which is generating functions via a macro, which looks like this:

File A (Provided file I can't change anything here):

```
#define FUNCTION_GENERATOR(NUM) \
void MyGeneratedFunctionNo##NUM##(void) \
{ \
     another_function_call(NUM); \
} \

FUNCTION_GENERATOR(1)
FUNCTION_GENERATOR(2)
FUNCTION_GENERATOR(3)
```

File B (My file where I wanna use function pointers to the generated functions from File A):

```
typedef void (*function_ptr) (void);
function_ptr func_array[3];
func_array[0] = MyGeneratedFunctionNo1;
func_array[1] = MyGeneratedFunctionNo2;
func_array[2] = MyGeneratedFunctionNo3;
...
```

Naturally the compiler complains that MyGeneratedFunctionNo1, MyGeneratedFunctionNo2, MyGeneratedFunctionNo3 are not defined.

**Is there any way to use function pointers with this
generated functions?**

Comment: Have you considered using templates instead?

Comment: It isn't possible to change the setup in File A => Huge project, lot of legacy ... and politics ...

Comment: You will have to make a macro that generates similar function declarations then. (Well, being a macro is optional, actually)

Comment: Can't you have another macro `FUNCTION_DECLARATOR` that does the same as `FUNCTION_GENERATOR` but without adding the function's body (i.e., declaring them instead of defining them)? File B would then refer a header that contains those declarations

Comment: File A already has undefined behavior; IIRC, it won't compile with g++ (but I don't have access to g++ here, so I can't reverify).

Comment: @JamesKanze Just for future reference, ideone.com is a great tool for checking things like that even if you don't have a development environment on your computer. (It also uses g++ as its C++ compiler.)

Comment: @us2012 Thanks.  (I actually do have access to g++, but it means starting up a remote desktop on a machine located elsewhere, with all that entails.  And at home, I only have g++, because my home computer is a Linux box.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with function pointers per se. You will not be able to access these functions from other translation units in any way, pointers or not, because they are not declared in other translation units.

The typical macro based technique implies providing and using *two* macros: one for generating declarations and one for generating definitions

```
#define FUNCTION_GENERATOR_DECL(NUM) \
void MyGeneratedFunctionNo##NUM(void);

#define FUNCTION_GENERATOR_DEF(NUM) \
void MyGeneratedFunctionNo##NUM(void) \
{ \
     another_function_call(NUM); \
}
```

After that you use the "definition" macro instantiations in some implementation file (as you already do)

```
FUNCTION_GENERATOR_DEF(1)
FUNCTION_GENERATOR_DEF(2)
FUNCTION_GENERATOR_DEF(3)
```

and you typically place the "declarator" macro instantiations into some header file.

```
FUNCTION_GENERATOR_DECL(1)
FUNCTION_GENERATOR_DECL(2)
FUNCTION_GENERATOR_DECL(3)
```

**P.S.** Also, note an important subtle point mentioned by @James Kanze in the comments (and which I missed initailly). The `##` operator shall not be used to form invalid preprocessing tokens. In the preprocessor grammar `(` is a separate independent preprocessing token (punctuator), while the function name is also a separate independent preprocessing token (identifier). If you attempt to forcefully concatenate the function name to the `(` by using the `##` operator, you'll end up with an invalid preprocessing token and undefined behavior.

Don't concatenate the `(` to the function name. Remove the second `##` from your macro definition. It will work as intended without it.

Comment: You might add that the second `##` in the definition causes undefined behavior, and should be removed.  (I have no idea why it would have been put there in the first place.)

Answer (score 2):

Just like any other function, you have to **declare** them. This is typically done in a header file.

You can do this directly, or you can define a macro similar to the one you have that **defines** the function.

Concretely, place this in a header file, which you include in **both** the file you define your functions in and in the file you use them:

```
extern void MyGeneratedFunctionNo1(void);
```